# Google Scripts JSON question - total novice teacher trying to help students

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-slides

Sorry - I don't have a clue how JSON works. I'm a teacher and trying to add a Translate facility to my Google slides to help the students whose first language isn't English.

I used this: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/slides/quickstart/translate - I assume it's OK because it's from G Suite Developer Add-ons as one of the Example editor Add-ons.

Then I hit a problem when saving the script and tried to solve it from here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes.

When I went into Scopes under Properties, it gave me these:

2 OAuth Scopes required by the script:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui

So I went into appsscript.json and this was already there:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I then added this to the bottom:

```
{
  ...
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
  ...
}
```

but when I save it, I get this:

```
Unexpected character ('.' (code 46)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [Source: (String)"{ "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney", "dependencies": { }, "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER", "runtimeVersion": "V8" } { ... "oauthScopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui" ], ... } "; line: 10, column: 4]
```

I've tried googling and using the JSON Validator, but don't have a clue apart from there clearly being a problem with the code.

If you are able to help, I'd very much appreciate it to help my students.

Cheers

Jon

Comment: There shouldn't be `...` at json. Remove it. It signifies the previous part inside `{}` and not a literal `...`. For the most part, you don't need to touch json: *Then I hit a problem*: What was the problem?

Comment: Thanks very much indeed - that makes tremendous sense. Your question prompted me to try with my personal Google account. I didn't have the security problem, but the Translate sidebar didn't work. That's too many problems with it, so I've decided to leave it as too hard currently. Appreciate your help. @TheMaster

Comment: If you  explain a problem, I could help. Honestly don't think it's that hard

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster - I really appreciate your approach. It's exactly the type I hope I give to my students.

 I think the two issues are: (i) I need permissions to use the Add-on within my school's domain. I think I can work through this, but have hit the problem that even with using my personal Google account and authorising it, the Translate app just returns a blank screen when I press the button to translate.

That's the first place to start I suspect - how would you recommend I solve that puzzle please? I tried the simple logging but couldn't find any errors. Cheers Jon

Comment: Try looking into the "browser" console.Chrome or Firefox  DevTools

Comment: I seem to get this message: 
    No {message: "There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit", name: "TransportError", stack: "TransportError: There was an error during the tran…5593464-warden_bin_i18n_warden__en_gb.js:189:247)"

Comment: The error  doesn't seem to be specific. I suggest 1. creating a new slide , 2.new script, 3. copy and paste the script. 4.clear browser cache. and try again?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - was busy teaching and family things. I did it again and it worked!! May have been clearing the cache which I haven't done for a long time. Thank you so much @TheMaster Very much appreciated - this will help my students. Cheers Jon

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is due to the way you have your nested array in the JSON object.

Check this link out about JSON, you will see a section about arrays as well.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Thanks - I had a look at this and am afraid I am still not sure how to fix the code. The first portion (timezone etc) on its own is OK when saved. The second portion on its own (oauthScopes) gets the error. I can't identify an error - sorry I am very much a beginner.